# How to fetch 5 most recent values and number of count in a column SQL

Tags: php, sql

According to the table, I have to count the top 3 most frequent bookID and the count of the bookID.

[image: table]

I have figured out how to get the top 3 , however  I couldn't figured how to display the number of count in the bracket after the comma.

I have to put these into the brackets separate by commas, it look like this:

```
[top1 bookid , the number of count] => [17,6]
[top2 bookid , the number of count] => [13,6]
[top3 bookid , the number of count] => [16,5]
```

```
$query ="SELECT bookID FROM issue_books GROUP BY bookID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 ";

$query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  foreach ($query_run as $row)
  { 
    echo '['". $row['bookID'];.",".xxxxx."']';
  }
```

Is there any way to display the count of the frequency number together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `count(*)` to the select list:

```php
$query =
"SELECT bookID, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM issue_books GROUP BY bookID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 ";

$query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

foreach ($query_run as $row)
{ 
    echo '[' . $row['bookID']; . ',' . $row['cnt'] . ']';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the count to the select clause?

```
$query = "SELECT bookID, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM issue_books GROUP BY bookID ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 3 ";
$query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
foreach ($query_run as $row) {
    echo "[" . $row['bookID'] . ", " . $row['cnt'] . "]\n";
}
```